# Startup no .net core 2.2 e .net core 3.1

Tags: c#, mvc, asp.net-core

Estou fazendo o curso de MVC core do desenvolvedor.io, mas no curso é usado o .net core 2.2 e estou usando a versão 3.1. Na criação de um projeto MVC do zero o código de configuração das rotas no Startup.cs do .netcore 2.2 é:

```
app.UseMvc(routes =>
{
    routes.MapRoute("default", "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

    //routes.MapRoute(
    //    name: "default",
    //    template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}"
    //    )
});
```

E no .net core 3.1 é:

```
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
    endpoints.MapGet("/", async context =>
    {
        await context.Response.WriteAsync("Hello World!");
    });
});
```

Tentei usar o código do 2.2 no 3.1, mas não está funcionando, porque o código já está depreciado. Eu gostaria de saber a diferença entre os dois códigos, por exemplo, pra que eu uso o `endpoints.MapGet` no 3.1. Qual foi a mudança que fizeram entre o .net core 2.2 e 3.1 no `Startup.cs`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Olá, na versão do Core 3.0 ou 3.1 a configuração é

```
    app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
    {
        endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
            name: "default",
            pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
    });
```

O MapGet método é usado para definir um ponto final. Um ponto final é algo que pode ser:
Selecionado, combinando o método URL e HTTP.

Você pode ler mais sobre o assunto aqui:
https://aregcode.com/blog/2019/dotnetcore-understanding-aspnet-endpoint-routing/